# Responsive Grid with Borders on the Inside Only

Tags: css, responsive-design, grid, border

I am trying to create a responsive grid with borders on the inside divs only.

I do this by using border-right for each of the divs except the last one, which has no border. The problem comes when I use media queries to change the width of the box, shifting the boxes positions on the page, the last div becomes the first div of the next line, so it's missing a border.

Here is the [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/acrosby6/z6xzpt8s/).

The HTML:

```
<div class = "box">
    <p>Box 1</p>
</div>

<div class = "box even">
    <p>Box 2</p>
</div>

<div class = "box">
    <p>Box 3</p>
</div>

<div class = "box last even">
    <p>Box 4</p>
</div>

<div class = "box">
    <p>Box 1</p>
</div>

<div class = "box even">
    <p>Box 2</p>
</div>

<div class = "box">
    <p>Box 3</p>
</div>

<div class = "box last even">
    <p>Box 4</p>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.box {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;   
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.box.last {
     border: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .box {
        width: 33.3333333333%;
    }

    .box.last {
        border-right: 1px solid black;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    .box {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .box.even {
        border: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    .box {
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
    }
}
```

At above 600px, the boxes are 25% (so four side by side).

At 450px, the boxes are 50%, which was ok by adding a new class.  But this gets tricky with odd numbers. So at 451 - 600px, boxes at 33.3%, I'm missing the borders.

Does anyone know how to make this easy? Or is my whole approach wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need even and last classes. nth-child() does the trick.

http://jsfiddle.net/dzyyubz6/1/

```
<div class = "box">
    <p>Box 1</p>
</div>

<div class = "box">
    <p>Box 2</p>
</div>

<div class = "box">
    <p>Box 3</p>
</div>

<div class = "box">
    <p>Box 4</p>
</div>

<div class = "box">
    <p>Box 1</p>
</div>

<div class = "box">
    <p>Box 2</p>
</div>

<div class = "box">
    <p>Box 3</p>
</div>

<div class = "box">
    <p>Box 4</p>
</div>

.box {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;   
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
.box:nth-child(4n + 4){
    border: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .box {
        width: 33.3333333333%;
    }
    .box:nth-child(4n + 4){
        border-right: 1px solid black;
    }
    .box:nth-child(3n + 3){
        border: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    .box {
        width: 50%;
    }
     .box:nth-child(3n + 3){
        border-right: 1px solid black;
    }
     .box:nth-child(2n + 2){
        border: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    .box {
        width: 100%;
        border: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not even know about the nth-child feature! Much appreciated.

Comment: I would appreciate if you click on the tick mark next to my answer. :)

Comment: Please be aware that there is no browser supprt for the nth-child selector in IE<9, Chrome<4.0 & Firefox<3.5!

Answer (score 1):

This idea only works if you can use the new [css-grid](http://grid.malven.co/) ruleset. Assuming you can (browser support wise), you can create a inner border by combining a `grid-gap` with a painted underlying absolutely positioned element which is offset underneath the actual cell to create a border illusion.

**Pros**

- adaptable, even if you don't have enough elements to fill the entire row, only the existing elements will have a border
- no specific `nth-child` css targeting at all. changing the grid row count doesn't effect the borders.
- borders don't clash or combine to create thicker than intended ones

**Cons**

- needs `css-grid` to work
- (as far as this example) to remove the outer edge borders (top/right/bottom/left) you need `overflow: hidden` on the grid

HTML

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-cell">
    <div class="cell-content">1</div>
  </div>
<div>
```

CSS/SCSS

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);

  // prevents ::before borders from looking offset if not enough cells 
  grid-gap: 1px;
  // remove the edge borders
  overflow: hidden;
}

.grid-cell {
  position: relative;
}

// create the illusion of a border
.grid-cell::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  // match the grid gap for border thickness
  top: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  // this becomes the border, and handles overlap
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.cell-content {
  position: relative;
  // fill in the cell color
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g6sc253n/1/)